# "@context": "/api/contexts/Error" + error 500 in my apiplateform

Tags: api, symfony

I'm using APIPLATFORM in my symfony project to connect sites of the map to their template. And sites in my API are now rendering an 500 error.
In the GET/API/SITES I have the following json file. This is the beginning.
[image]

It has happened two times before, and I fixed it. Do you know how to avoid this error this time? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I just deleted the topos with id = 0 . And it worked again. Thank you.